# How to get 18 columns in Bootstrap grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5

I use the latest Bootstrap version 3.2.0 with MVC 5, and I'm new to both.

What I would like to do is make a grid with 18 columns using Bootstrap. I can see over here http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-less that it is indeed possible by changing `@grid-columns`.

So in my MVC view I try this:

```
<style>
    @grid-columns: 18;
</style>
```

Followed by this HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-1">col 1</div>
  <div class="col-lg-1">col 2</div>
  <div class="col-lg-1">col 3</div>
  <div class="col-lg-1">col 4</div>
  <div class="col-lg-1">col 5</div>
  <div class="col-lg-1">col 6</div>
  <div class="col-lg-1">col 7</div>
  <div class="col-lg-1">col 8</div>
  <div class="col-lg-1">col 9</div>
  <div class="col-lg-1">col 10</div>
  <div class="col-lg-1">col 11</div>
  <div class="col-lg-1">col 12</div>
  <div class="col-lg-1">col 13</div>
  <div class="col-lg-1">col 14</div>
  <div class="col-lg-1">col 15</div>
  <div class="col-lg-1">col 16</div>
  <div class="col-lg-1">col 17</div>
  <div class="col-lg-1">col 18</div>
</div>
```

But that doesn't work. What should I do to get this working?

Thanks!

Comment: Just to check here, you understand that this is a LESS statement not a CSS statement? And you have a LESS compiler on your machine?

Comment: No, I did not know it's a LESS statement, and I don't think I have a LESS compiler installed. So LESS compilation is needed to get a grid with 18 columns?

Comment: See my answer below. :)

Comment: Just a little follow up. I found this plugin called gridline.js which will allow you to make any number of columns in your bootstrap grid. You can find it here: http://tmaiaroto.github.io/gridline/

Comment: See also [this related thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30906659/279844).

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in another answer you can download a custom version of Bootstrap with 18 columns by going to [Bootstrap Customizer](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) and making a custom bootstrap file. However, you should realize that this is not a future-proof solution. If ever you wanted to update your bootstrap you'd need to update those variables the same way to get a version that won't break your features.

I recommend your get familiar with `LESS` and how it's compiled so you can make your own `LESS` source files. This is the `LESS` homepage: http://lesscss.org/

To get you started with that understand a few simple things: One, `LESS` is an extension to `CSS` that requires a special compiler that will translate it into standard `CSS`. It is this standard `CSS` that you include on your site, not the `LESS` itself. Two, it is possible to have `LESS` compile on demand with certain engines but it's just a bit tricky to set up. You can think of this relationship with this analogy: As `php` is to `html` so is `LESS` to `CSS`

Answer (score 0):

simply download your custom version of Bootstrap with 18 columns and problem solved. Go to [Bootstrap Customizer](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) then in the right column under **Less Variables** look for *Media queries breakpoints*

You can also use the resulting customized version to study how to do it yourself should you need it in the future